# Azure Key Vault setting a tag removes ability to "show" secret

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I've been doing some Key Vault testing and have noticed some odd behavior. I can create a secret and view the value just fine.

#### Before:

[image]

However, I've noticed when I create a tag on a secret, the secret is removed from the **Show Secret Value** area (shown below):

#### After:

[image]

I know the secret still exists as my UI is able to pull it and show it on a web page so it's not lost; just the option to view it is lost.

This feels like a bug unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Same issue. That didn't solve it for me. I can set tags and a secret through the REST API and can view the secret just fine. For whatever reason if I do it through the web UI it removes the secret from view for me. Doesn't seem to be a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its correct, because I assume you haven't [configure any permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-secure-your-key-vault#management-plane-and-rbac).

Comment: I can see the secret before I set the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I test in my site and can reproduce your issue.

As Volodymyr said, to grant a user read access to Key Vault properties and tags, but not access to data (keys, secrets, or certificates), you need to [grant management plane access with RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-secure-your-key-vault#resource-endpoints).

[image]

To grant access to a user to manage key vaults, you assign a predefined key vault `Contributor role` to the user. Then you could see the `Show Secret Value` area as before.
[image]